# Android, an array within an array?

Tags: java

How can I put some arrays into one larger holder array?

Here are my arrays:

```
int [] mySoundArray = {R.raw.piano_c1, R.raw.piano_d1};

int [] mySoundArrayTwo = {R.raw.piano_e1, R.raw.piano_f1};
```

I've tried this but it errors:

```
int [] totalSoundArray = {mySoundArray, mySoundArrayTwo};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *this syntax*:

```
int [][] totalSoundArray = {mySoundArray, mySoundArrayTwo};
```

**Explanation:** this is because what you are creating is an array of an array of ints.

```
int i // an int
int[] ii // an array of ints
int[][] iii // an array of an array of ints
```